# Building NodeJs applications in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, node.js, eclipse-plugin, nodeclipse

Is there a way to build a NodeJs application using Nodeclipse on Eclipse IDE?

I´m trying to find an option in the plugin, but nothing about it is shown. Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: There isn't any eclipse plugin available at the moment for NodeJS development in Eclipse with code generation support. I would recommend https://c9.io/ which gives code complete support as well. This is close to a good IDE i have come across so far.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i will take a close on c9. There is an opensource alternative for private workspaces?

Comment: Hey @andresmafia, actually c9.io does give you one private workspace for free. But if you are doing an open source project, then you get the workspace for free without any space limitations as i remember.

Comment: Go for [**Webstorm**](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) it is the best for Javascript development. I am sure you will love it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite clear question. So I am giving possible answer to stay in Q-A format of this site.

JavaScript does not required building any binaries, so there is no build step, unless you want to minimize .js

When creating new application, you can use any tool (most of them use CLI). 
Then run
`nodeclipse -p` in project folder, and import in Eclipse as existing Eclipse project. 
See https://npmjs.org/package/nodeclipse .
Or you can create empty project, then press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+D</kbd> to open shell for selected project/folder and continue in shell to generate project.

Since 0.10 there is code completion for base Node.js modules.

If you have spesific ideas and request, raise an issue at https://github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/